# C# How do I prevent duplicates in sql by checking two conditions (Combobox.text and datetimepicker.value to sql values(int and DBnull)

Tags: c#, sql, duplicates

I would like to prevent duplicates if they satisfy two conditions, that the Book number(CboSifraKnjige.Text) is double, and the date of return  is DBnull in sql table and the datetimepicker(DTPVracanje) is unchecked. With this code, the add (dodaj) button adds and replicates, a couple of hundred rows (this is the error).

```
private void BtnDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Dodaj means Add in Croatian
{
    if (DTPVracanje.Checked == false)//DTPvracanje is a datetimepicker
    {
        for (int Row = 0; Row < DataGridView.Rows.Count;  Row++)
        {
            if (DataGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == CboSifraKnjige.Text 
                   && DataGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[5].Value.Equals(
                         Convert.IsDBNull(DTPVracanje.Value))) //column 5 contains DBnull if DTPVracanje is unchecked
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Knjiga je vani");//Book is out in Croatian[
            }
            else
            {
                Dodaj();
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint and see why conditions are not satisfied? We have no idea what data you have and what is in textbox.

Comment: Double is floating point... look up "floating point comparison" it might b an issue here.

Comment: I'll give you a tip - `Convert.IsDBNull(DTPVracanje.Value)` will **never** return `true`, since `null` and `DBNull` are not the same thing.